# Help needed in calculating the related change

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I need help solving an issue of mine.

The question goes like this:

Q) $A$ is a lighthouse and $\overline{BC}$ is the shoreline. It is a right triangle and the lighthouse $A$ is perpendicular to the shoreline. The lighthouse turns once a second so $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=2\pi$ radians/second. Let the distance from the lighthouse to shoreline at $B$ be the perpendicular distance $100$ and the light move up from $B$ to $C$ and the distance $\overline{BC}=y$. And finally the hypotenuse is $z$.
Find a relationship between the rate of change of $z$ to $y$ with respect to time.

My solution was to use the Pythagorean theorem
So
$$z^2 = y^2 + 100^2$$
differentiating with respect to time implicity:
$$2z\frac{dz}{dt} = 2y\frac{dy}{dt}$$
so $$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{y}{z}\times \frac{dy}{dt}$$
as $\frac{y}{z} = \sin\theta$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \sin\theta\frac{dy}{dt}$$
This is the right answer. I tried another approach I do not know why this method does not work.
I tried the following
$$y = z\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(y) = \frac{d}{dt}(z\sin\theta)$$
From here if I use product rule on the RHS then I do not get the right answer. I do not know why this approach is not working.
I will appreciate any insight as to why this does not work or if I am doing this question wrong.

Thank you and stay safe!!!!

Comment: $z_t= y_t \sin \theta$ describes the relationship between the rates of change at a "snapshot" in time, whereas the second also relates the change in $\theta$ in time... the equation $y = z \sin \theta$ encodes more information

Comment: What is $z_t$ did you mean dz/dt. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes I meant $z_t = dz/dt$!

Comment: Thanks for the input. So are you saying that the first equation works only for a certain snapshot of $\theta$. I thought as z and y changes so does the theta as the light house is rotating

Comment: Yes it does! But the first equation doesn't include this information. It only tells us how fast z changes, compared to how fast y changes. The second equation, though, does include information on $d\theta/dt$.

Comment: Oh I got it then. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

From the first picture (left), you've got $$\begin{split}y^2+100^2&=z^2\\
\frac{dz}{dt}&=\frac{y}{z}\frac{dy}{dt}\end{split}$$

Now suppose you are given the additional information that $\theta$ is $\angle A$ (right). You can indeed find the relationship between dz/dt and dy/dt from this, you just need 2 equations now.

$$\begin{split}\sin\theta&=\frac{y}{z}\\
\cos\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}&=-\frac{y}{z^2}\frac{dz}{dt}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{dy}{dt}\end{split}$$

and

$$\begin{split}\cos\theta&=\frac{100}{z}\\
-\sin\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}&=-\frac{100}{z^2}\frac{dz}{dt}\\
\Rightarrow\frac{d\theta}{dt}&=\frac{100}{z^2\sin\theta}\frac{dz}{dt}\end{split}$$

Go back to above

$$\begin{split}\frac{100\cot \theta}{z^2}\frac{dz}{dt}&=-\frac{y}{z^2}\frac{dz}{dt}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
\left(\frac{100^2}{yz^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}\right)\frac{dz}{dt}&=\frac{1}{z}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
\underbrace{\left(\frac{100^2+y^2}{z^2}\right)}_{=\frac{z^2}{z^2}=1}\frac{dz}{dt}&=\frac{y}{z}\frac{dy}{dt}\end{split}$$